# typeahead.bundle.js:374 Uncaught TypeError: this._send is not a function (in ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js

I'm trying to make a component for country `typeahead` in ReactJS. I use remote source of `Bloodhound`,

but when i tried, it keeps giving me an error：

> typeahead.bundle.js:374 Uncaught TypeError: this._send is not a function

it doesn't even evoke the url request in my remote server

If I change the source to local Bloodhound source, it works well.

Here is the code:

```
class TypeaheadCountry extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.inputText = React.createRef();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSelected = this.handleSelected.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){  

    /* for local source, it works well
    var src = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(['id','name']),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: [
        {name:'UNITED STATES',id:'US'},
        {name:'CANADA',id:'CA'},
        ]
    });
    */

    /* but for remote source, always give me this error：
        typeahead.bundle.js:374 Uncaught TypeError: this._send is not a function
          at Transport._get (typeahead.bundle.js:374)
          at later (typeahead.bundle.js:113)
    */
    var src = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      remote: {
          url: '/country/typeahead?q=%QUERY',
          wildcard: '%QUERY'
      },
    });
    src.initialize();
    this.$el = $(this.inputText.current);

    this.$el.typeahead({
      hint: false,
      highlight: false,
      minLength: 1
    },{
      name: 'country-list',
      source: src,
      display: 'name',
      displayKey: 'id',
      templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="card card-body">',
            'no data match',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: function (data){return '<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><dl>'+'<dt class="text-primary">'+data.id+'</dt><dd>'+data.name+'</dd></dl></div>'}
      }
    });

    var self = this;
    this.$el.on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, data) {
      self.handleSelected(e,data);
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {

    this.$el.off('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', this.handleSelected);
    this.$el.off('change', this.handleChange);
    this.$el.typeahead('destroy');
  }
  handleChange(e, data) {
    this.props.onChange(e, data);
  }
  handleSelected(e, data) {
    this.props.onSelected(e, data);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputText} name={this.props.name} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="typeahead" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps throwing this error message:

```
typeahead.bundle.js:374 Uncaught TypeError: this._send is not a function
          at Transport._get (typeahead.bundle.js:374)
          at later (typeahead.bundle.js:113)
```

Comment: As far as im concerned self is a reserved keyword, just do it the ES6 way. `this.$el.on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', (e, data) => {
      this.handleSelected(e,data);
    });`

Comment: Hi George thanks. But that self variable doesn't cause any problem in my case. I've changed the name also no difference, since this has nothing to do with the remote Bloodhound problem. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! 
it's the "slim" version of jquery.3x.x.**slim**.min problem. switch to non-slim, and it works fine. Thanks for sharing your thought.